# Unable to display the label after the button is clicked In python using PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

the button is calling the clickMethod Function,as it is dispalying  "You clicked PushButton" in the console but it is not displaying the label

```
import sys

import self as self
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel, QLineEdit, QPushButton
from PyQt5.uic.properties import QtWidgets

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    w = QWidget()
    VideoUrl = QLabel(w)
    VideoUrl.setText('videoURL')
    VideoUrl.move(100, 40)
    InputText = QLineEdit(w)
    InputText.move(100, 60)
    Button = QPushButton(w)
    Button.setText('Download')
    Button.move(100, 100)


def clickMethod():
    print("You clicked PushButton")
    output = QLabel(w)
    output.setText("clicked")
    output.move(100, 70)


Button.clicked.connect(clickMethod)

w.resize(700, 500)

w.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Be a bit more careful with your code logic. Testing against __name__ doesn't make much sense if you then refer to objects that could have only been created there: if `__name__` is different (for example, if you try to import the file), `app`, `w` and `Button` will not exist, and your program will crash.

Comment: thanks for the input,can you provide alternative solutions,like documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `ouput.show()` at the end of clickMethod.